# Ubuntu 14.04 cant detect USB mouse

Tags: 14.04, usb, mouse, touchpad

I recently installed Ubuntu and lately seem to be having a problem operating my usb mouse from it.

```
kj@kj-SVE15115ENW:~$ xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer
2: "Virtual core pointer"   [XPointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
13: "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"    [XExtensionPointer]
10: "USB Optical Mouse" [XExtensionPointer]
kj@kj-SVE15115ENW:~$ xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer
2: "Virtual core pointer"   [XPointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
13: "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"    [XExtensionPointer]
kj@kj-SVE15115ENW:~$ xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer
2: "Virtual core pointer"   [XPointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
13: "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"    [XExtensionPointer]
10: "USB Optical Mouse" [XExtensionPointer]
kj@kj-SVE15115ENW:~$ xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer
2: "Virtual core pointer"   [XPointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
13: "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"    [XExtensionPointer]
kj@kj-SVE15115ENW:~$ xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer
2: "Virtual core pointer"   [XPointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
13: "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"    [XExtensionPointer]
```

as you can see , it seems to be detecting the USB optical mouse for a minute. then it automatically seems to be removing the same from the xsetpointer.

I tried plugging the mouse into various usb ports (have 4 of them) and I seem to be getting the problem across all usb ports. the USB ports seem to work as i have no problem when connecting my external.

Also , I’m unable to use the trackpad as well as the cursor seems to 'twitch' violently and renders it unusable.

Please let me know how i can fix this issue. The mouse issue is very recent as it was working well for the past 2 weeks

P.S - the mouse seems to be working fine with my windows laptop

KJ